# Enabled or disabled checkbox in gridview using datatable in C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

In my mysql table the users enabled are divided by `level` and `perimeter`

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| uname   | ulevel | uperimeter |
+---------+--------+------------+
| 5207459 |      1 | 400X       |
| 5204759 |      1 | 4SXR       |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

I need to enable a `checkbox` in the `gridview` for each user, when your level is `1` value and for your enabling `perimeter`.

This is my code-behind in ASP.NET written in C#. But for the `uname 5207459` in `gridview` is enabled only the checkbox with `uperimeter 4SXR`, instead of `uperimeter 400X` and `uperimeter 4SXR`.

Help me to do it.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    ulevel = reader.GetString(0);
    uperimeter = reader.GetString(1);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("p_ulevel", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("p_uperimeter", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { ulevel, uperimeter });

    var tulevel2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(z => z.Field<string>("p_ulevel")).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(ulevel));
    var tuperimeter2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(z => z.Field<string>("p_uperimeter")).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(uperimeter));

    if (Convert.ToInt32(tulevel2) == 1 && tuperimeter2.ToString().Contains(tuperimeter.ToString()))
    {                                
        chkRow.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        chkRow.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

**Update**

If change operator `&&`

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(tulevel2) == 1 && tuperimeter2.ToString().Contains(tuperimeter.ToString()))
```

to operator `||`

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(tulevel2) == 1 || tuperimeter2.ToString().Contains(tuperimeter.ToString()))
```

For the `uname 5207459` in `gridview` is enabled all checkbox with `uperimeter 400X` and `uperimeter 4SXR`.

I don't understand...

Comment: Few questions why are you creating `DataTable` inside `while (reader.Read())`? Another why you have written so complex statement are you not sure there is column in each record or not?

Comment: @शेखर thanks for reply, please see **Update** on the question...